# hide and show part of GEO sorted buttons list

Tags: cordova, sorting, html-lists, geo, display

I am busy for days now to figure out the following issue, hope someone here could help me.

**the situation:**
Iam building a phonegap(build) application.
On the home screen i have in total 12 buttons of the same size but with different content.
In the first situation only the 4 nearest (based on geolocation) buttons are allowed to show themselves. (geoloaction works all ready)
After pushing the button "show more" the other 8 buttons can be showed (then we have the total of 12).

I tried to do this by using javascript with the style.display="none" or "block"
This works for 90% but this cause another issue.
For example if a button with display.style="none" is close to the user (location) it will not disappear in the nearest 4 positions. If i push the button "show more" then it works. How do i get it write?

javascript for sorting the buttons on geolocation

**Javascript for showing handeling UL sorting by Geolocation**

```js
   <script>
    navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(sortResults);

 
  function sortResults(position) {
    // Grab current position
    var latlon = new LatLon(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
 
    var locations = document.getElementById('locations');
    var locationList = locations.querySelectorAll('li');
    var locationArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(locationList, 0);

 
    locationArray.sort(function(a,b){
      var locA  = a.getAttribute('data-latlon').split(',');
      var locB  = b.getAttribute('data-latlon').split(',');
 
      distA = latlon.distanceTo(new LatLon(Number(locA[0]),Number(locA[1])));
      distB = latlon.distanceTo(new LatLon(Number(locB[0]),Number(locB[1])));
      return distA - distB;
     });
 
    //Reorder the list
    locations.innerHTML = "";
    locationArray.forEach(function(el) {
      locations.appendChild(el);
    });
 
};

</script>
```

**HTML for the button**

```html
<li id="but-pos1-12" data-latlon="">
<div class="col-3 col-m-4 col-mp-6">
<div class="but" id="but-pos12">
<a href="historie.html" class="but-link">
<span class="but-pont-name"></span><br><span class="but-pont-name2"></span>
<img src="img/boot.png" class="but-pont-img">
<div id="but-small-img-pos12" align="center">
<img src="" class="but-pont-small-img" id="pos12-1">
<img src="" class="but-pont-small-img" id="pos12-2">
<img src="" class="but-pont-small-img" id="pos12-3">
<img src="" class="but-pont-small-img" id="pos12-4">
<img src="" class="but-pont-small-img" id="pos12-5">
<img src="" class="but-pont-small-img" id="pos12-6">
<img src="" class="but-pont-small-img" id="pos12-7">
</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</li>
```

**Javascript for showing and hiding**

```js
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady(){

document.getElementById("but-anderepont-show").addEventListener("click", showotherponts, false);
document.getElementById("but-anderepont-hide").addEventListener("click", hideotherponts, false);


}
function hideotherponts(){
 
 document.getElementById("but-anderepont-hide").style.display = 'none';
 document.getElementById("but-anderepont-show").style.display = 'inline-block';
 document.getElementById("but-pos1-5").style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById("but-pos1-6").style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById("but-pos1-7").style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById("but-pos1-8").style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById("but-pos1-9").style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById("but-pos1-10").style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById("but-pos1-11").style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById("but-pos1-12").style.display = "none";
}

function showotherponts(){
 
 document.getElementById("but-anderepont-show").style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById("but-anderepont-hide").style.display = "inline-block";
 document.getElementById("but-pos1-5").style.display = "block";
 document.getElementById("but-pos1-6").style.display = "block";
 document.getElementById("but-pos1-7").style.display = "block";
 document.getElementById("but-pos1-8").style.display = "block";
 document.getElementById("but-pos1-9").style.display = "block";
 document.getElementById("but-pos1-10").style.display = "block";
 document.getElementById("but-pos1-11").style.display = "block";
 document.getElementById("but-pos1-12").style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: Please post your code for displaying/hiding the buttons themselves.

Comment: Now with script for showing and hiding, thanks for viewing.